# What programs can a user use to make the desktop more pleasant/enhance/better

Tags: 11.04, effects

At this moment I know of Unity which looks much better than the default Gnome desktop that comes in 11.04. Also Compiz adds effects so that enhances the view. But what about other tools that make the view of the desktop much more pleasant to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To tweak Compiz you can install
  **CompizConfig Settings Manager**.
  It has many options, some of them
  might break your user interface so
  be cautious.
- **Conky** is a system monitor that
  can display just about anything,
  either on your root desktop or in
  its own window. Conky has many
  built-in objects, as well as the
  ability to execute external programs
  or scripts (either external or
  through built-in lua support). It is
  not easy to configure Conky, but you
  can download many pre-configured
  files. Tech Drive-in [featured](http://www.techdrivein.com/2010/12/13-breathtaking-conky-configurations.html)
  some really great Conky themes not
  so long ago. OMG! Ubuntu! also
  [featured](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/five-beautifully-simple-conky-themes/) some Conky themes.
- WebUpd8 created an [Ubuntu Themes
  PPA](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/announcing-webupd8-themes-ppa.html) with many awesome GNOME
  **themes**.